# Scraping script into Html with Beautiful Soup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to scraping  into Html with beautiful soup but i've difficult scraping desired data.
i've write this but in this way i found all script in the Html.

```
response = s.get(dataObject.url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
script = soup.findAll('script')
```

I need to take 'pf_id' value from this html:

```
<script>
        var qSVariables = ""; // Store Variables
        
        var prodzoom_control = 'on';
        var siteSubDirectory = "";
        var addbsktTimeElapseVal = "1000";
        var pageidentifie = 'product';
        var promoSliderHours = "720";
        
        var isKnockout = true;
        
        
        
                    var product_model_wears_lable = 'Model is wearing';
                
                
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myVariantGridEM = new variantGrid('myVariantGridEM'); // Load the variant grid class
        variants = { "40387759":{'sequence':'','opt2_sequence':'991','wasprice':'RRP €107.50','wasprice_net':'RRP €0.00','price':'€107.50','price_net':'€107.50','sale_item':'false','manufacturer_sku':'','manufacturer_name':'Jordan','option1':'White / University Red / White','option2':'6','option3':'','pf_id':'4038775','sell':'true','stock_status':'in stock','option2_js':'Size 6','option2_mob_js':'Size: 6','stock_int':1,'lead_text':'','promoicon':'<img src=\"/images/articles/icon_freedelivery_large.png\"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split string by "," and then look for 'pf_id'. If you find it split by ":" this time and get second value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<script>
        var qSVariables = ""; // Store Variables
        var prodzoom_control = 'on';
        var siteSubDirectory = "";
        var addbsktTimeElapseVal = "1000";
        var pageidentifie = 'product';
        var promoSliderHours = "720";
        var isKnockout = true
        var product_model_wears_lable = 'Model is wearing'; 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myVariantGridEM = new variantGrid('myVariantGridEM'); // Load the variant grid class
        variants = { "40387759":{'sequence':'','opt2_sequence':'991','wasprice':'RRP €107.50','wasprice_net':'RRP €0.00','price':'€107.50','price_net':'€107.50','sale_item':'false','manufacturer_sku':'','manufacturer_name':'Jordan','option1':'White / University Red / White','option2':'6','option3':'','pf_id':'4038775','sell':'true','stock_status':'in stock','option2_js':'Size 6','option2_mob_js':'Size: 6','stock_int':1,'lead_text':'','promoicon':'<img src=\"/images/articles/icon_freedelivery_large.png\"
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

script = soup.find("script")

splited_text = str(script).split(',')
result = ""
for i in range(len(splited_text)):
    if "pf_id" in splited_text[i]:
        result = splited_text[i].split(":")[1]
        break

print(result)
```